# Trying to get an image to show dependent on a result of a previous function

Tags: javascript, html, list, random

I am very new to javascript so please be very gentle and explain things as much as you can be bothered to please ;)

I am trying to create a button that will randomly select a name from a list and display it with an image of the person (hero if you know what this is for).

I have so far the a button that runs a function that selects the name randomly, I'm just having difficulty getting the image to show...

```
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Random</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var strings = ['Axe', 'Bane', 'Batrider' ];

var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * strings.length);

var randomString = strings[randomIndex];
document.write(' ' + randomString);
}
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var picData = [
            ['Axe','http://ponky.org/~ropedy/DC/icons/heroes/Axe.png'],
            ['Bane','http://ponky.org/~ropedy/DC/icons/heroes/Bane.png'],
            ['Batrider','http://ponky.org/~ropedy/DC/icons/heroes/Batrider.png']
        ];
        window.onload=myFunction(){
            var cookieValue = 'Axe';  
            for(i=0; i < picData.length; i++){
                if(cookieValue == picData[i][0]) {
                   document.getElementById('imgCont').src = picData[i][1];
                   i=picData.length;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>

    <div>
        <img id="imgCont" src="" alt="" />
    </div>
```

Comment: You mean javascript no Java

Comment: Just a quick comment, use `break` to exit out of your `for` loop early instead of manipulating the loop index.

Comment: console.log(picData[i][1]) in the for loop. What do you see in the console?

Answer (score 2):

Change your `window.onload` to something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    myFunction();
    // then the rest of your stuff to set the .src
}
```

But it looks like what you actually want to do is move the stuff for setting the `.src` to a separate function so you can call it in response to your button click.

Something like:

```
var picData = [
    ['Axe','http://ponky.org/~ropedy/DC/icons/heroes/Axe.png'],
    ['Bane','http://ponky.org/~ropedy/DC/icons/heroes/Bane.png'],
    ['Batrider','http://ponky.org/~ropedy/DC/icons/heroes/Batrider.png']
];

function myFunction()
{
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * picData.length);

    var randomString = picData[randomIndex][0];
    document.write(' ' + randomString);    // Note: I'd generally avoid document.write

    document.getElementById('imgCont').src = picData[randomIndex][1];
}
```

Now you can call this both from `onload` and `onclick` if you want to give you a random image when first loaded and a random image each time you click the button.

For easy to read and maintain code, I'd also replace your array or arrays with an array of object literals:

```
var picData = [
    {name:'Axe', imageUrl:'http://ponky.org/~ropedy/DC/icons/heroes/Axe.png'},
    {name:'Bane', imageUrl:'http://ponky.org/~ropedy/DC/icons/heroes/Bane.png'},
    {name:'Batrider', imageUrl:'http://ponky.org/~ropedy/DC/icons/heroes/Batrider.png'}
];
```

Why? Because now instead of:

```
 picData[randomIndex][1];
```

I can write:

```
 picData[randomIndex].imageUrl;
```

Which is a lot more readable and makes it clearer what you are actually doing.

Comment: I would suggest using more meaningful names, for instance `pick_random_image` instead of `MyFunction`. According to what the OP said, now seems a good time to learn the importance of proper naming :).